# How could we change the position of the path for the child node, link and node's position with different parameters in tree d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I've used  tree diagram in d3js where I'm stuck while positioning some of the path, nodes and links to fit in different location as per the child which has 1 parameter different.
So, from that we could compare and can change whatever we want but I'm unable to find the way to compare in tree diagram d3js and change my child nodes path and node bit in different direction.

My json

```
    {"icon":"/images/OracleConnector.png","input":false,"category":"STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S0 <br> Type : OracleConnectorPX <br> OutputPins : V0S0P1 <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : null","name":"OraLOG_BOT_AS_ADDRESS","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S0P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S4|V0S4P4","name":"LnkLogBotAsAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/PxJoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S4 <br> Type : PxJoin <br> OutputPins : V0S4P3 <br> InputPins : V0S4P4|V0S4P2 <br> Partner : null","name":"JoinLogBotAniraAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S4P3 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S7|V0S7P9","name":"LnkRdupBotAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/PxJoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S7 <br> Type : PxJoin <br> OutputPins : V0S7P5 <br> InputPins : V0S7P9|V0S7P6 <br> Partner : null","name":"JoinBotAndSxp","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S7P5 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S53|V0S53P1","name":"LnkAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/PxSVTransformer.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S53 <br> Type : CTransformerStage <br> OutputPins : V0S53P2|V0S53P3 <br> InputPins : V0S53P1 <br> Partner : null","name":"XfmNewAndUpdatedRecords","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S53P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S56|V0S56P1","name":"LnkNewRecords","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"
/images/PxJoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S56 <br> Type : PxJoin <br> OutputPins : V0S56P3 <br> InputPins : V0S56P1|V0S56P2 <br> Partner : null","name":"JoinBotToSxpNewAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"
/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S56P3 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S62|V0S62P4","name":"LnkNewRecordsToRdup","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/PxDataSet.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S62 <br> Type : PxDataSet <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : V0S62P4 <br> Partner : null","name":"DsLogBotAsAddressNew","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S62P4 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S56|V0S56P3","name":"LnkNewRecordsToRdup","value":"5"}],"type":"PxDataSet"}]},{"icon":"/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S56P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S53|V0S53P2","name":"LnkNewRecords","value":"5"},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S56P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S55|V0S55P1","name":"LnkNewAddressLkp","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/OracleConnector.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S55 <br> Type : OracleConnectorPX <br> OutputPins : V0S55P1 <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : null","name":"OraSxpAniraSohoOrder","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S55P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S56|V0S56P2","name":"LnkNewAddressLkp","value":"5"}],"type":"OracleConnectorPX"}]}],"type":"PxJoin"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S53P3 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S45|V0S45P4","name":"LnkUpdatedRecords","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/PxSequentialFile.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S45 <br> Type : PxCopy <br> OutputPins : V0S45P5|V0S45P6 <br> InputPins : V0S45P4 <br> Partner : null","name":"CpyToSxpUpdatedAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S45P5 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S25|V0S25P2","name":"LnkLogBotUpdatedAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/PxDataSet.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S25 <br> Type : PxDataSet <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : V0S25P2 <br> Partner : null","name":"DsLogBotAsAddressUpdated","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S25P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S45|V0S45P5","name":"LnkLogBotUpdatedAddress","value":"5"}],"type":"PxDataSet"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S45P6 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S73|V0S73P1","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsSrt","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/PxJoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S73 <br> Type : PxSort <br> OutputPins : V0S73P2 <br> InputPins : V0S73P1 <br> Partner : null","name":"SrtSxpAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S73P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S72|V0S72P1","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsFlt","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/PxJoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S72 <br> Type : PxFilter <br> OutputPins : V0S72P2 <br> InputPins : V0S72P1 <br> Partner : null","name":"FltSxpAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S72P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S70|V0S70P2","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsToSxp","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/OracleConnector.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S70 <br> Type : OracleConnectorPX <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : V0S70P2 <br> Partner : null","name":"OraSxpAddressUpdate","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S70P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S72|V0S72P2","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsToSxp","value":"5"}],"type":"OracleConnectorPX"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S72P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S73|V0S73P2","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsFlt","value":"5"}],"type":"PxFilter"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S73P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S45|V0S45P6","name":"LnkUpdatedRecordsSrt","value":"5"}],"type":"PxSort"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S45P4 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S53|V0S53P3","name":"LnkUpdatedRecords","value":"5"}],"type":"PxCopy"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S53P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S7|V0S7P5","name":"LnkAddress","value":"5"}],"type":"CTransformerStage"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S7P9 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S4|V0S4P3","name":"LnkRdupBotAddress","value":"5"},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S7P6 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S9|V0S9P1","name":"LnkSxpAniraAddressLkp","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/OracleConnector.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S9 <br> Type : OracleConnectorPX <br> OutputPins : V0S9P1 <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : null","name":"OraSxpAddressAndOrder","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S9P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S7|V0S7P6","name":"LnkSxpAniraAddressLkp","value":"5"}],"type":"OracleConnectorPX"}]}],"type":"PxJoin"}]},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S4P4 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S0|V0S0P1","name":"LnkLogBotAsAddress","value":"5"},{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":true,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S4P2 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S1|V0S1P1","name":"LnkBotAniraAddress","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/OracleConnector.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S1 <br> Type : OracleConnectorPX <br> OutputPins : V0S1P1 <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : null","name":"OraBotAniraSohoAddressAndOrder","value":"5","children":[{"icon":"/MetaDataDiscovery/resources/common/images/etljoin.png","input":false,"category":"ETL_STAGE","level":"Green","details":"Identifier : V0S1P1 <br> Type : null <br> OutputPins : null <br> InputPins : null <br> Partner : V0S4|V0S4P2","name":"LnkBotAniraAddress","value":"5"}],"type":"OracleConnectorPX"}]}],"type":"PxJoin"}]}],"type":"OracleConnectorPX"};
```

My Path for the position to the nodes...

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { 
                            return d.target.input == false ? "url(#arrowhead)" : "";
            })
            .attr("marker-start", function(d) { 
                    return d.target.input == true ? "url(#arrowdown)" : "";
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    return d.target.input == false ? d.target.level : "red";
            })
            .attr("d", function(d) {
```

Here if input is true then we need to change the position of the path...

```
if(d.source.input == true)
{
    return_elbow = elbow(d);
    console.log("return_elbow", return_elbow);
    return return_elbow;
}
else
{
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
}
```

Here i'm adding path and comparing with the input...
Please check out the code and guys if you know the way...Please let me know...